# Date and Size information of files and folders just in one window available

Tags: total-commander

Date and Size information of files and folders just in one window available.

There is just in the left window informations about the contents visible. 
I'm quite sure this is a konfiguration issue of the TC. 
But I didn't find the right solution via Google and Co.

Answer (score 0):

I found it.

1. **select** the window in which you miss the information
2. go to **show** and select **Full**

It is quite easy, if you know how to do.